# Twitter Rails gem "Unable to verify your credentials", Initializer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, initialization, figaro-ruby

I'm using the [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) and [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) but my credentials aren't being stored. Here's my setup:

config/initializers/twitter.rb

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
  config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
end
```

config/application.yml:

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "12345"
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "12345"
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "12345"
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "12345"
```

Placing the below in a View results in a "Unable to verify your credentials" error which I believe is caused by the initializer not correctly storing my credentials.

```
<%=
@client =  Twitter::REST::Client.new
@client.user_timeline("cnn") %>
```

I've tried putting various items in a Controller but nothings works. Via console:

```
client =  Twitter::REST::Client.new
=> #<Twitter::REST::Client:0x007fadf06364b0>
client.consumer_key
 => nil
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client =  Twitter::REST::Client.new` is creating a new object with no params; it is not reusing what has been configured in `config/initializers/twitter.rb`

Try putting the initialization code & the accessing code in the controller together as follows:

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
  config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
end

@client.user_timeline("cnn")
```